# Loopback 4 Debugger nodemon Solution

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, loopbackjs, nodemon

How to debug loopback 4 / node application with nodemon in visual studio code?

Looking for a solution that rebuilds the app when the loopback typescript code is changed. With option for debugging.

Regards,

Kelvijn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own nodemon.json in root project source and put this in file

```
{
  "ignore": [
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    ".git",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "watch": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exec": "npm start",
  "ext": "ts"
}
```

and run `nodemon` that's. Just make sure you installed nodemon in global scope.

Comment: The simplest solution, IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a solution to debug Loopback 4/node.js. If anyone has suggestions please do, this is the first solution that really does what I want.

Start Debugger by running:

```
npm run debug
```

With **nodemon** run the below command

```
nodemon --exec run debug
```

Add breakpoints by clicking on the left side of the line numbers in visual studio code.

Then in Visual Studio Code start application on debug mode by

```
Visual Studio Code (top-bar) -> Debug -> Start Debugging
```

**package.json**

```
"debug": "npm run build && node --nolazy --inspect-brk=9229 .",
"build": "lb-tsc es2017 --outDir dist"
```

**launch.json**

```
{
 "version": "0.2.0",
 "configurations": [
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "timeout": 1000000,
  "name": "Attach",
  "port": 9229,
  "restart": true
}
   ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

**Note:** This file is by default extended by loopback, so you don't have to modify this.

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "lib": ["es2015"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "platforms"]
}
```

**Application structure**

[image: application structure]

Comment: Is this available on the docs then please provide a link as well.

Comment: Works for me by doing changes as suggested. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: gives error : `'run' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

Comment: For me, the `--nolazy` flag made the difference, because of async/await functions

Answer (score 2):

This is an **alternative** solution for `nodemon`.

`tsc-watch` is a similar tool that can be used with `loopback 4`. Basically, it works similar to the nodemon. To add `tsc-watch` as dev package,

1. run `npm install tsc-watch --save-dev` in your project location
2. add following lines to the `package.json > scripts`

   `"start": "node -r source-map-support/register .",
   "dev": "tsc-watch -b --onSuccess \"npm start\""`
3. now run `npm run dev`

For more details visit *tsc-watch* on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-watch) or [github](https://github.com/gilamran/tsc-watch)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers here I have manage to have something that works for my setup. I use yarn with loopback 4. Thanks to @dat-ho for the starting point.

First install `nodemon` in global scope

then add the `nodemon` config to package.json. I added this at the bottom of the file after `devDependencies`.

```
 "nodemonConfig": {
    "verbose": true,
    "watch": [
      "src/"
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "dist/*"
    ],
    "ext": "ts",
    "exec": "yarn run clean && yarn start"
  }
```

The changes from previous answer was that nodemon detects the `npm start` script and it re runs `npm start` fine, but it does not rebuild and the changes were not shown in the running code. so I added the line `"exec": "yarn run clean && yarn start"` to clean and rerun the `npm start` command.

You can then add the following `start:dev` command to the package.json `scripts` section:

```
"start": "node -r source-map-support/register .",
"start:dev": "nodemon '--inspect'",
```

From there just run `yarn start:dev` and will rebuild when any typescript file changes. Hope this works for you guys. It took me a substantial amount of research to having this working. Hopefully the loopback guys can have something similar in future.